# Swift retrieve data from Database

Tags: database, swift, xcode6

I checked many tutorials and I can't find what I want to do.
What I want to do, is storing GPS coordinates in my data base; so far no problem. In my tableViewControllerCell, I don't want use "subtitle" style, but use UILabel. My problem is I have this code which works well with "subtitle" style (see below). But I want to do with my own custom Label.

Can someone help me?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let list = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List

    cell.textLabel?.text = list.item
    var qty = list.qty
    var note = list.note
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Qty:\(qty) -\(note)"

    return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom UITableViewCell for example myTableViewCell, assign it to the cell in the storyboard selecting the cell and selecting the class in the inspector (the same you did for you view controller) 
After that when you retrieving the cell you must cast to you new class as below:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell
```

Now you can call your properties in the cell like

```
cell.myField = "value"
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to know how to use a custom view cell for your table view.

If you want to create a custom table view cell in storyboard:

1. Go to storyboard and select your table view (assuming you already have one).
2. In the field "Prototype Cells" change it to "1".
3. Add whatever you want to add in the prototype cell (displayed in the table view). In your case it would be extra labels.
4. Create a custom `UITableViewCell` class.
5. Go back to storyboard and assign the new custom table view cell class to your prototype. To do this, you'll have to select the cell (make sure it's the cell which is selected by checking in the left pane of the storyboard. Click the "Identity inspector" and assign the class to the cell.
6. While the cell is still selected, go back to "Attributes inspector" and give it an identifier in the "Identifier" field. Something like "cell" should be enough.
7. Click the Assistent editor and `ALT` click on your custom table view cell file.
8. Create outlets for your labels in this custom table view cell class. It should be looking like this:

   ```
   class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

       @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
       @IBOutlet weak var labelCustom: UILabel!
   }
   ```
9. In your view controller you can now add things to your cell as shown below:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

       let data = something[indexPath.row]

       cell.labelName.text = data.name
       cell.labelCustom.text = String(data.number)

       return cell
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I do have some problem to make it worked. I will try to work on it little bet more and come back to you. Thank you again

Comment: I do believe I did what you said, but I keep having this error. UItableViewCell does not have a member named label. I do have an IBOulet for my label names "Label".

Comment: This error can be caused by a few things. Did you cast it to the custom table view cell when you are creating the cell?